# Django on_delete=CASCADE not working, can't delete parent row using raw SQL

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, cascade

Django models:

```
class Parent (Model):

    name = CharField (max_length = _MAX_NAME_LENGTH, unique = True)

class Child (Model):

    name = CharField (max_length = _MAX_NAME_LENGTH, unique = True)

    parent = ForeignKey (Parent, on_delete = CASCADE)
```

Create some data:

```
p = Parent (name='parentname')
p.save ()

c = Child (name='childname', parent=p)
c.save ()
```

Delete parent, expecting child to be deleted via cascade:

```
DELETE FROM `basedb_parent` WHERE `basedb_parent`.`id` = 1
```

> #1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`idat_prealpha_0_1`.`basedb_child`, CONSTRAINT `basedb_child_parent_id_d6f3ee55_fk_basedb_parent_id` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `basedb_parent` (`id`))

Although running `p.delete()` in the Python code *does* delete the Parent and Child rows. I know this is actually happening in the underlying MySQL database because the `AUTO_INCREMENT` table attribute increases (so it's not being shortcutted by any kind of fancy cache in Django).

Why doesn't my `DELETE FROM` query work, while `p.delete()` does work?